# Java, JPA, Glassfish, Invalid resource : jdbc/__default__pm

Tags: java, jpa, deployment, glassfish

I use Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5), JPA, EclipseLink, MySQL

I created MySQL pool via Glassfish admin panel. Ping to MySQL from GF admin panel is ok.

I created app with persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="myUnit">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDBName"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="myPass"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I tried to deploy it and got the error:

```
Invalid resource : jdbc/__default__pm

[#|2012-11-16T02:20:59.480+0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=43;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Invalid resource : jdbc/__default__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/__default__pm
```

Stacktrace in GF log is huge. Started by

```
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:540)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:469)
at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
....
```

Does anyone have ideas what happened and what to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have only created a MySQL connection pool, you must also create a JDBC resource. This can be created from the context menu above the one you used to create the connection pool.

[image: Example Glassfish jdbc resource setup]

In my Glassfish, my JDBC resource, jdbc/__default is using the connection pool mysql_lemon.

Comment: but, from where comes the *__pm <-- ??

Comment: __pm is a suffix used to allow broader access to the JDBC resource. See [@Bernhard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117122/754300)

Answer (score 6):

the __nontx and __pm are extensions to the pool.
documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beamr/index.html
(somewhere else http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/jdbc.htm#GSDVG00185 and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/transaction-service.htm#GSDVG00512)

first **__pm**

from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gavro/index.html

> Allowing Non-Component Callers
>
> You can allow non-Java-EE components, such as servlet filters,
>   lifecycle modules, and third party persistence managers, to use this
>   JDBC connection pool. The returned connection is automatically
>   enlisted with the transaction context obtained from the transaction
>   manager. Standard Java EE components can also use such pools.
>   Connections obtained by non-component callers are not automatically
>   closed at the end of a transaction by the container. They must be
>   explicitly closed by the caller.
>
> You can enable non-component callers in the following ways:
>
> Check the Allow Non Component Callers box on the Edit Connection Pool Advanced Attributes page in the Administration Console. The
>   default is false. For more information, click the Help button in the
>   Administration Console.
>
> Specify the ----allownoncomponentcallers option in the asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool command. For more information, see the
>   Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Reference Manual.
>
> Specify the allow-non-component-callers option in the asadmin set command. For example:
>
> asadmin set domain1.resources.jdbc-connection-pool.DerbyPool.allow-non-component-callers=true
>
> For more information, see the Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Reference Manual.
>
> Create a JDBC resource with a __pm suffix.

and **__nontx**

from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beamu/index.html

> Using Non-Transactional Connections
>
> You can specify a non-transactional database connection in any of
>   these ways:
>
> Check the Non-Transactional Connections box on the New JDBC Connection Pool or Edit Connection Pool page in the Administration
>   Console. The default is unchecked. For more information, click the
>   Help button in the Administration Console.
>
> Specify the ----nontransactionalconnections option in the asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool command. For more information, see the
>   Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Reference Manual.
>
> Specify the non-transactional-connections option in the asadmin set command. For example:
>
> asadmin set domain1.resources.jdbc-connection-pool.DerbyPool.non-transactional-connections=true
>
> For more information, see the Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Reference Manual.
>
> Use the DataSource implementation in the GlassFish Server, which provides a getNonTxConnection method. This method retrieves a JDBC
>   connection that is not in the scope of any transaction. There are two
>   variants.
>
> public java.sql.Connection getNonTxConnection() throws java.sql.SQLException
>
> public java.sql.Connection getNonTxConnection(String user, String password) throws java.sql.SQLException
>
> Create a resource with the JNDI name ending in __nontx. This forces all connections looked up using this resource to be non
>   transactional.

Answer (score 4):

(The same post of mine but with proper account now):

When configuring persistence with your setup, you only set the JNDI name for the JDBC pool in persistence.xml. Optional, you may set the target database name.

```
<persistence-unit name="foo" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysql</jta-data-source>
    <!--optional-->
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL4"/>
</persistence-unit>
```

I also encourage to change the 'drop-and-create-table' to 'create-tables', so that you don't loose data, and this should be be providing EclipseLink's properties in following way:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

and also handy

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
```

that will create schema and sql scripts.

For more information visit: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL
or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/gbwmj/index.html

Comment: The key is change the jta-data-source in persistence.xml file to connect with the resource that was be created

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The solution (for anybody that still have this issue):

1. if you are using the NetBeans IDE 8.1 with Glassfish 4.1.1, I advise you to change it to Glassfish 4.1
2. Go to the left panel in NetBeans.

Click on `services > server > glassfish` then right-click (in Glassfish server) and choose view domain admin console, a web page should show up.

Go to the left and choose `resources > JDBC` and `JDBC connection pool`.

Add a new connection pool by clicking on `new`, type the name of your pool.

Next, choose the `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` and the `datadriver` (in my case is MySQL) and click next.

After that, you should enter all the needed information for your database.

3. Go back to `Resources > JDBC`. This time, `JDBC Resources` create a new JDBC resources (for me, I named it `jdbc/test`). Don't forget to link it with the connection pool you already created.
4. In NetBeans go to your `ejb` project and modify the `persistence.xml` file. Change the `datasource` to the database resource (in my case `jdbc/test`) and save all.

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I run/deploy an app on a server created by netbeans instalattion wizard.

To solve I downloaded the last glassfish version from official site and went to:
Netbeans > "Service's Tab" > "Servers" > "Add Server...".

Remember to change your project configurations to use the new glassfish server instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.I set jdbc connection pool and jdbc resource in admin consol. But i did not set data source in persistence.xml .

```
  <persistence-unit name="OnlinePrintService-warPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/your-name</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to [a NetBeans bug they say they had fixed](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233481) but seemingly they had not. As a solution, I ended up removing `glassfish-resources.xml` altogether (as I couldn't make `persistence.xml` pick it up with any kind of the workarounds) and using `@DataSourceDefinition` annotation instead.

My configuration uses a separate `DataSourceBean.java` file for `@DataSourceDefinition`:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/jdbc/myDataSource",
    className="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource",
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=myDB",
    user="myuser",
    password="mypassword"
)
public class DataSourceBean {
}
```

`persistence.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I firmly believe it is caused by some remainig-cache.

Just after I've done

```
asadmin remove-domain domain1
asadmin create-domain domain1 
firefox http://localhost:4848
```

Now `__pm` is not appended anymore to JDBC resources.

if this does not help, then I assume that you are using

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

this should be replaced with 
e.g.

```
em=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DefaultPU(PUT_PERSISTANCE_UNIT_NAME_HERE").createEntityManager();
String ret="Hello " + txt + ", "+ em.createNamedQuery("Usertable.findAll").getResultList().get(0).toString() +" !" ;
em.close();
```

Comment: why should i create the EntityManager by myself (and not using Annotation)? from where did you get that code?

Comment: If it works for you then you should use annotations, but if you are forced to use some buggy version or something, then hardcoding it might help