# What are the __pm and __nontx suffixes?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, glassfish, persistence

My java EE application is giving following error when i try to run the application on glassfish server. It says **"Invalid resource : jdbc/busservice__nontx"**. Where should i look to fix this error? Previously it was giving error with "jdbc/busservice__pm". Once I created JDBC resource and connected with connection pool, error disappeared. However i'm still getting error with "jdbc/busservice__nontx"

```
  Info:   PER02100: Could not load Toplink Essentials. Assuming this is an upgrade from V2. Switching Persistence Unit [BusReservationPU] to use [org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider] as JPA provider. If you intend to use Toplink Essentials, please ensure that it is visible to your application."
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Severe:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/busservice__nontx
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupNonTxResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:559)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupNonTxResource(PersistenceHelper.java:59)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupNonTxDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
```

Comment: I do not have experience with Glassfish, but try marking the DataSource as being JTA in both Glassfish and your persistence.xml file (or at least being of the same type: either resource-local or JTA).

Comment: If you didnn't already solve the problem you should add your `persistence.xml` to the question.

Comment: see documentation http://stackoverflow.com/a/32117122/1498669

Answer (score 0):

Do not add "jdbc/busservice__pm" to your Glassfish JDBC Resources, just add it as "jdbc/busservice". It looks like the __pm and __nontx are some internal names that it adds to the end of your jdbc name internally, and when you specifically add it will mess it up and throw that error.