# Create a Derby DB in Glassfish and connect to Java EE application

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, derby

I'm trying to write a Java EE application that uses JPA to access a database. Until now I just used the @Entity annotation and left everything else to the default state (for example the persistence.xml file was using _TimerPool as the jta-data-source, and I didn't create any db).

So I wanted to try and use an actual database. I went into the Services screen, JavaBD > Create new database, set it up with a name and password.

The DB's url: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Prova

Then I created the persistence.xml file for my application through Glassfish's wizard:

```
  <persistence-unit name="JobsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/Prova</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.target" value="database-and-scripts"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Prova"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="paolo"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="paolo"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

And when I try to deploy I get this exception:

```
    Grave:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/Prova__pm), (applicationName=Jobs) }
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/Prova__pm), (applicationName=Jobs) }
```

Seems to be related to the JNDI naming. Of what I honestly don't know, I'm still trying to learn. If I go to Glassfish's console, under the JNDI listing I can't see anything that seems to be related to my database (not in JDBC Connection Pools nor in JDBC Resources). What should I do?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407505/java-jpa-glassfish-invalid-resource-jdbc-default-pm

Comment: Latest versions of Glassfish are broken, when you try to click on new in the "jdbc resources" you get a nice exception. That's great.

Comment: have you consider using payara or wildfly?

Comment: If you spend so much time using GF, payara will be no pain transition but if you are new to GF also i will strongly recommend you to use WildFly.

Comment: I have to use glassfish for my class. I'll look into WildFly after, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To configure PersistenceUnit for EE container you have to use `jta-data-source` and `transaction-type="JTA"`. For `jta-data-source` you have to specify JNDI name of JDBC ConnectionPool which have to be configured in EE container (glassfish server in your case). There is tutorial [How to set up a JDBC Connection Pool on Glassfish](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool). Also in this case PersistenceUnit properties like

```
 <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Prova"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="paolo"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="paolo"/>
```

will be ignored for EE container (see [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm#CJAJGAEC)).
To use this properties you can configure PersistenceUnit  for SE environment. Before this i recommend you to read article [differences between RESOURCE_LOCAL and JTA persistence contexts](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html). 
Configuration for SE application will be look like:

```
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Prova"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="paolo"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="paolo"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```