# Whille deploying RESTful webservice, Shows error JdbcDataSource. not found

Tags: rest, glassfish, jndi, connection-pooling, netbeans-8

I have been trying to create my first RESTful execrcise [using](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm). But I am unable to deploy module due to error "com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/playerDB__pm"

I checked and I have JNDI, daata source created.
[image]

Unlike specified in link. I am using:
-Netbeans 8.0.3, Java EE 7, GlassFish Server 4.

Also I have checked GlassFish is running fine.

Edit 1:
I have re-checked my 'Services' tab, and I could not find `jdbc/__playedDB` ,even though I have created it.

[image]

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407505/java-jpa-glassfish-invalid-resource-jdbc-default-pm  will  help you

Comment: Thanks, this seems little related. But as I just updated I am completely unable to find my pool or resource. (I have clearly created it, but they seem missing).

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug, the JDBC resource file is not being created (atleast with versions I am using: GlassFish 4.1, Netbeans 8.0.2). Using GlassFish manually [create](http://www.nagazuka.nl/2014/03/invalid-resource-with-netbeans-8_27.html).

There could still be different error untill you set following connectins:
database(data source) <- connection pool <- JNDI.